# How to update only a single value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
 const docRef = firestore.collection("SequenceId").doc(doc.id);

 docRef.update({

                sequencenumber: {
                    [x]: false 
                  }

             })
```

Currently my database is 
[image: My current database]

> After the above code is executed my database
>   [image]

But i want only the value of 2: to be updated to false, while maintaining 3: and 4: . Here 3: and 4: gets deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't currently offer the ability to update a single item in an indexed array.  Your alternative is to read the entire array from the document, modify it in memory, then write the entire array back to the document.

The only array update operations available are adding a new array ("arrayUnion") and removing an item from an array ("arrayRemove").  You can [read the documentation for those operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: if i have like 50 elements in an array , is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: My answer applies to arrays of all sizes.