# How to do arrayUnion on an array of objects inside another array of objects in firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a comment section in my react app. The comment section has following data structure in the firestore:-

```
    comments: [{
        comment: "First comment",
        replies: [{
            reply: "first reply"
        }]
    },{
        comment: "Second comment",
        replies: [{
            reply: "first reply"
        }]
    }]
```

If I want to add a new comment I do this by: -

```
db.collection("myCollection").doc("0").update({
    comments: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
        comment: "New Comment",
        replies: []
    })
})
```

Now, what I actually want to do is to do is to add a new reply to the existing comment. But I can't find any way to do it. For example, I want this to happen in the data structure defined above: -

```
    comments: [{
        comment: "First comment",
        replies: [{
            reply: "first reply"
        },{
            reply: "second reply"
        }]
    },{
        comment: "Second comment",
        replies: [{
            reply: "first reply"
        }]
    }]
```

So how can I do this?

Please help me solve this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to update an array element by its index, which is not an atomic operation on Firestore.

You'll need to:

1. Read the document and retrieve the `comments` array from it.
2. Update the `comments` array in your application code.
3. Write the updated `comments` array back to the document.

If you were to store the comments in a subcollection, you can probably use an `arrayUnion` to update a specific comment, since then the replies are a top-level field in that document. But I doubt it is worth the added overhead of the additional documents and document read operations in this scenario.

Also see:

- [Firestore Update single item in an array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187985/firestore-update-single-item-in-an-array-field/52189143#52189143)
- [How can I update an object inside of an array in firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417069/how-can-i-update-an-object-inside-of-an-array-in-firestore/62418875#62418875)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am actually doing. Reading the whole array of objects then sending back after modifying. Was just wondering if there was an easy way to do this. Anyways, Thank you!