# How to update a specific index of an array in firebase reactjs

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

check this image for better understading of question

[image]

this function only updates first index

```
function handleBooking(){
    
    const groundref = doc(db,'Owner', props.id)
   
    updateDoc(groundref,{
        slots: {Sat: [{available: book , status: status}]}
        } ).then(response => {
            alert("updated")
        }).catch(error =>{
            console.log(error.message)
        })  
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore Update single item in an array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187985/firestore-update-single-item-in-an-array-field), [How can I update an object inside of an array in firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417069/how-can-i-update-an-object-inside-of-an-array-in-firestore)

Comment: Firestore doesn't have an operation to update the contents of a specific array item in a document. You have to read the document into memory, modify the array, then update the array field back into the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to update a specific index of an array?

If the question is about Firestore, as also @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, Firestore doesn't have the capability to update an array by a specific index. You have to read the document, perform the changes in the array, and then update the array back to Firestore.

---

If it's about the Realtime Database, then to be able to modify a node inside the Realtime Database, then you have to create a reference that points exactly to that node. So for example, if you want to change the value of the `available` field of the first element from `false` to `true`, and the `slots` node is a child of the root reference, then the following reference is needed:

```
db/slots/Sat/0/available
```

Comment: The question was not correctly tagged and is actually asking about Firestore.